# How to enable window preview on task switcher on xfwm4 when default compositor in not running?

Tags: xfwm4, picom

I have installed and running [`picom-git`](https://github.com/yshui/picom) on Arch Linux. I disabled `xfce4`'s default compositor from `Settings Manager` > `Window Manager Tweaks` > `Compositor` > `Enable display compositing` (unticked). Now, window preview is gone from `xfwm4`(default `alt+tab` task switcher). How can I get back window preview while the default compositor is disabled?